# During undoing of a logged operation in database 'PROD_Search_Service_LinksStore', an error occurred at log record ID

Tags: database, sharepoint, database-restore

I'm not a true DBA as I tend to google a lot and have not had formal training though I have had 13 years of experience as a developer.  My Sharepoint Administration skills are really more as a developer.

This morning we received the following alert:

"During undoing of a logged operation in database 'PROD_Search_Service_LinksStore', an error occurred at log record ID (30235:3119:49). Typically, the specific failure is logged previously as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database or file from a backup, or repair the database."

Logging into SSMS, I can see the specific DB is now listed as suspect.

I found a site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/database-types-and-descriptions) that offered me some guidance on this.

"Perform a backup and restore of Search service application databases only when the SharePoint farm is fully stopped. When the SharePoint farm is stopped you can back up the farm to snapshots or make a backup with SQL Server tools to ensure the search indexes are synchronized with the search databases. Note that a restore must include all of this backup set."

1. This sounds like I cannot restore just the Links DB, but all four of the Sharepoint DBs.

Also:

"We do not support restoring search database backups that are not synchronized with the search indexes."

2. Perhaps I am not fully understanding this, but is there a reason preventing me from restoring and running a full crawl?  Would this correct the synchronization issue?
3. Is doing a repair my best option?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting our SQL box fixed this.